# Whether $g(y) = \min\limits_{x} f(x, y)$ is convex under some conditions

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Denote a convex function $f(x,y)$. Suppose that $f$ is convex with respect to $y$, and is a strongly convex quadratic function with respect to $x$.

Let
$$
d(y)=\arg\min_x f(x,y).
$$

Let $$g(y)=f(d(y),y).$$ Is function $g$ convex?

Due to the comment provided by River Li, function $g$ is not convex.

What if we add a condition: $f$ is further strongly convex with respect to $(x^T,y^T)^T$?

Comment: An example in which $g$ is not convex: $f(x, y) := (y^2+1)x^2 - 2(y+1)x$. Then $d(y) = \frac{y+1}{y^2+1}$ and $g(y) = - \frac{(y+1)^2}{y^2+1}$.

Comment: If $f(x, y)$ is (joint) convex with respect to $(x, y)$, then $g(y) = \min\limits_{x} f(x, y)$ is convex. See e.g. Page 88 in https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is convex with respect to $y$ then for every $x$, we have for $t\in(0,1)$
$$f(x,ty_1+(1-t)y_2) \leq tf(x,y_1) + (1-t)f(x,y_2)$$
Surely that means that whenever $x=d(y), y=ty_1+(1-t)y_2$ for any arbitrary function $d$ (including the one you provided), we should still have
$$f(d(y),ty_1+(1-t)y_2) \leq tf(d(y),y_1) + (1-t)f(d(y),y_2)$$
Which means (Edited to use convexity with respect to $x$ in line $3$)
$$g(ty_1+(1-t)y_2) = f(d(ty_1 + (1-t)y_2),ty_1 + (1-t)y_2)\\
= f(d(y),ty_1+(1-t)y_2) \leq tf(d(y),y_1) + (1-t)f(d(y),y_2) \\
< t^2f(d(y_1),y_1)+t(1-t)f(d(y_2),y_1)+t(1-t)f(d(y_1),y_2) + (1-t)^2f(d(y_2),y_2) \\
< tg(y_1) + (1-t)g(y_2) + t(1-t)\left(f(d(y_2),y_1) + f(d(y_1),y_2)\right)$$
So if $f$ is positive then $g$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to the definition of $g$, we have $g(y_1)=f(d(y_1),y_1)\leq f(d(y),y_1)$, where the inequality comes from $d(y_1)=\arg\min_x f(x,y_1)$. Similarly, we have $g(y_2)=f(d(y_2),y_2)\leq f(d(y),y_2)$. Those imply $tf(d(y),y_1) + (1-t)f(d(y),y_2) \geq tg(y_1) + (1-t)g(y_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I edited it. Hopefully this result is more useful